# What does maintenanceMode -7 mean on a mongo primary?

Tags: mongodb

I've recently promoted a new member to primary of a mongo replicaset.  Things seem to be running smoothly for several days and am not seeing any application symptoms of any problems.  However peeking at rs.status() today I noticed it's listing maintenanceMode -7.  I didn't think this should be possible as it's the primary.  I'm having trouble finding anything useful in the docs on what this means.

What does this mean?

```
    {
        "_id" : 26,
        "name" : "mongohost5:27032",
        "health" : 1,
        "state" : 1,
        "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
        "uptime" : 106966,
        "optime" : Timestamp(1379627877000, 77),
        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2013-09-19T21:57:57Z"),
        "maintenanceMode" : -7,
        "self" : true
    }
```

Comment: I'm not 100% this is what's going on but this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9338 seems related.  If so, it sounds like a bug, not a feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintenance mode is used when running certain commands, generally the [compact command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/).  What you have here is the bug mentioned in [SERVER-9338](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9338) whereby I am guessing you have run the compact command against your nodes several times.  There are some circumstances, especially when run on a primary when it will usually cause a change of state (i.e. it's not primary when the compact finishes), that cause `maintenanceMode` to be erroneously decremented.

As of writing this answer this is fixed in the development branch and has been marked for backport, though it has not (yet) been targeted for a release in the earlier versions.  Until the fix is released it should be safe to ignore the value, but I will do some testing to confirm and report back.